# Possible to Delete Directory/File Too Soon?

Tags: java, io

Ran into an oddity that I hope someone can help me with.

I have a test class that creates a temporary directory in C:\Temp, copies a zip file to it, runs about 31 simple unit tests and deletes my new temp directory upon shutdown.

I noticed that when I run the class in "normal-mode", my new directory isn't being deleted.

However, if I were to run it in "debug-mode" and step through the code for a couple seconds, then at the end of execution, my new temp directory IS deleted.

Just for kicks, I tried adding in a 5sec sleep at the start of my ShutdownHook and my new temp directory was deleted with no problems at all.

**So, is it possible that I'm creating and trying to delete this directory too quickly?**

Thanks for reading.

---

**Logic for creating the new temp directory:**

```
@BeforeClass
public static void initialSetup(){

//Create temp directory
tempDirectory_Path = Files.createTempDirectory(TEMP_DIRECTORY_NAME);

//Add a ShutdownHook
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
                TestTrueZipFileInput.deleteTempDirectory(tempDirectory_Path.toFile());
            }
        });

//Copy zip file to temp directory
FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(Paths.get(zip_File_URI).toFile(), tempDirectory_Path.toFile());
}
```

---

**Logic for deleting the new temp directory:**

```
 private static boolean deleteTempDirectory(File tempDirectory){
    if (tempDirectory.exists()) {
        File[] files = tempDirectory.listFiles();
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            if (files[i].isDirectory()) {
                deleteTempDirectory(files[i]);
            }else {
                files[i].delete();
            };
        }
    }
    return (tempDirectory.delete());
}
```

---

**With a Sleep value added to the ShutDownHook:**

```
@BeforeClass
public static void initialSetup(){

//Create temp directory
tempDirectory_Path = Files.createTempDirectory(TEMP_DIRECTORY_NAME);

//Add a ShutdownHook
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("Error during sleep");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Deleting Directory: " + tempDirectory_Path.toString());
    TestTrueZipFileInput.deleteTempDirectory(tempDirectory_Path.toFile());
}
});

//Copy zip file to temp directory
FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(Paths.get(zip_File_URI).toFile(), tempDirectory_Path.toFile());
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you using an `@AfterClass` method to delete the directory?

Comment: @nerherd

  I tried using an @AfterClass method but get the same result.

`@AfterClass`
`public static void tearDown(){`
`TestTrueZipFileInput.deleteTempDirectory(tempDirectory_Path.toFile());`
 `}`

Comment: Do you happen to have some files still open in directory? Make sure all files are properly closed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why the folder deletion is failing, but I'd like to suggest a different approach. Assuming you are running JUnit, I would suggest using the [Rules feature](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Rules) to automate the process of temporary folder creation and deletion.

For a temporary folder that will persist for the duration of the entire test case, you'll need the following line:

```
@ClassRule public static TemporaryFolder tempDirectory = new TemporaryFolder();
```

To access the folder wrapped by the TemporaryFolder instance

```
tempDirectory.getRoot()
```

JUnit will create the directory for you as a *BeforeClass* operation, and will also delete the directory and any child directories or files as an *AfterClass* operation so most of your setup and teardown code becomes unnecessary

Comment: Thanks a ton!  I didn't even know that this existed.  I replaced my logic with the ClassRule and a TemporaryFolder instance and all my problems are gone now.  You rock!

Thanks again.

Comment: No worries. Just remember you can change class level setup/teardown to test/method level by changing the ClassRule annotation to a Rule annoation, and removing the static flag. Enjoy